# create 24hour top table by pageview

Tags: mysql

how would i create a "last 24 hour top" table by pageviews if i have the following tables.

`movie: id, title`

`pageview: id, movie, vieweddate`

i need the third table like this

`top: id, movie, moviecount24`

so i would be able to make such query:

`select * from top24 order by viewcount24 desc limit 30`

i need to create `top` table using ONE mysql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select       
  pageview.id as pageview_id
  ,movie.title as move_title
  ,count(movie.id) as moviecount24
from pageview
inner join movie on (pageview.movie = movie.id)
where pageview.vieweddate between date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and now()
order by moviecount24 desc
limit 30;
```

Comment: i need a THIRD table named `top`

Comment: Insert into top select pageview.id as pageview_id ...., see yegor256's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Let me refactor Johan's response a bit:

```
INSERT INTO top
SELECT movie.id AS id, COUNT(movie.id) as moviecount24
FROM pageview
LEFT JOIN movie ON pageview.movie = movie.id
WHERE vieweddate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

`LEFT JOIN` is important here, since some movies may have zero views, but still should be present in the result.

Comment: zero views would hardly make it into the top 30...., so I'm puzzled why you would want to cache those results in table `top`. Still if you'd want to this would do the trick.